# A matrix class in java

Tags: java

I need to create a matrix class, which has 2 constructors, and a method which does a filter average to a number with the numbers around it in the matrix.

Here is what I came up with, but when I try to compile it, I get an error:
"array expected, Matrix found".

Help please !

```
/**
* This class represents a two dimensional Matrix 
* 
*/
public class Matrix
{
private int[][] _matrix;

/**
 * Constructs a Matrix from a two-dimensional array; the dimensions as well as the values of this Matrix will be the same as the dimensions and values of the two-dimensional array.
 */
public Matrix(int[][] array)
{
    for (int i=0; i < array.length;i++)
        for (int j=0; j < array[i].length;j++)
            _matrix[i][j] = array[i][j];
}

/**
 * Constructs a size1 by size2 Matrix of zeroes.
 */
public Matrix(int size1, int size2)
{
    for (int i=0; i < size1;i++)
        for (int j=0; j < size2;j++)
            _matrix[i][j]=0;
}

/**
 * Calculates and returns a copy of this Matrix after it has been filtered from noise. All pixels are represented by a number 0-255 inclusive. 
 * 
 * @return a copy of this Matrix after it has been filtered from noise
 */
public Matrix imageFilterAverage()
{
    Matrix newMatrix = new Matrix(_matrix);


    for (int i=0; i < _matrix.length;i++)
        for (int j=0; i < _matrix[i].length;j++)
            newMatrix[i][j] =  _matrix[i-1][j-1] + _matrix[i-1][j] + _matrix[i-1][j+1] + _matrix[i][j-1] + _matrix[i][j] + _matrix[i][j+1] + _matrix[i+1][j-1] + _matrix[i+1][j] + _matrix[i+1][j+1];
}


}
```

**Edit**

Hey guys, thanks for the help. Now I'm trying to make a toString method, That will print the matrix, with tab between the numbers, but after the last number in the last row, there won't be a tab.
Can't really get it working, don't know how to return it. But here is what I came up with so far:

```
 public String toString()
 { 
 for (int i=0; i < _matrix.length; i++) { 
    for (int j=0; j < _matrix[i].length; j++) 
       if (j == (_matrix[i].length - 1)) 
              System.out.print(_matrix[i][j]); 
       else System.out.print(_matrix[i][j] + "\t"); 
     System.out.println(); 
 } 


}
```

Comment: I highly suggest a good beginner's book on Java or the tutorials from Oracle. It appears you're typing random things in and expecting them to compile/work. `newMatrix[i][j]` ... your object isn't an array.

Comment: You're trying to `[]` to access the internal array of your matrix, but you're using it on the matrix itself rather than the array inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change imageFilterAverage()

```
public Matrix imageFilterAverage() {
    Matrix newMatrix = new Matrix(_matrix);
    for (int i=0; i < _matrix.length;i++)
        for (int j=0; i < _matrix[i].length;j++)
            newMatrix._matrix[i][j] =  _matrix[i-1][j-1] + _matrix[i-1][j] + _matrix[i-1][j+1] + _matrix[i][j-1] + _matrix[i][j] + _matrix[i][j+1] + _matrix[i+1][j-1] + _matrix[i+1][j] + _matrix[i+1][j+1];
    return newMatrix;
}
```

compile error will go, but you probably have more bugs in the code, eg the second constructor must be like this

```
/**
 * Constructs a size1 by size2 Matrix of zeroes.
 */
public Matrix(int size1, int size2) {
    _matrix = new int[size1][size2];
}
```

The first constructor is also wrong because you first need to create _matrix then copy data.

Answer (score 2):

```
newMatrix[i][j] =  _matrix[i-1][j-1] + _matrix[i-1][j] + _matrix[i-1][j+1] + _matrix[i][j-1] + _matrix[i][j] + _matrix[i][j+1] + _matrix[i+1][j-1] + _matrix[i+1][j] + _matrix[i+1][j+1];
```

This line causes an error because you can't use `[]` on a `Matrix`. You can only use that operator on an array.

Also, this will cause an error because you haven't set `_matrix` equal to anything:

```
for (int i=0; i < array.length;i++)
    for (int j=0; j < array[i].length;j++)
        _matrix[i][j] = array[i][j];
```

Add `_matrix = new int[array.length][array[0].length]` before those lines.